# how to make text inputs always autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It seems like some text inputs immediately give me a sort of "dropdown" with values I've filled in in the past. Other times not. Is there a way I can "*encourage*" this behavior in the input boxes? Why does this sometimes happen and sometimes not? Do I need to give a repeat user a cookie or some other device to ensure they will have this feature, or is there some jquery option? (since I'm already using that).

Comment: What you're seeing is a browser function.  If you want your own, use an autocomplete plugin, like [this one](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

Comment: A total guess but I think that most of the browsers are actually using the "name" or "id" attribute to autocomplete the user input.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks! I could probably make something like this work with a cookie on my own, but is there any plugin readily available that makes the list populate from user-specific data without use of a database?

Comment: Browsers remember that information when a form is actually submitted. Ajax based forms have issue because of that.

Comment: Have you seen the *datalist* element?  http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/new-form-features-in-html5/#datalist

Comment: Is it particular data that you would like to have autocomplete, like your first, last names, address, etc, or must it be everything that you have typed in the past?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Comment: @epascarello What's the way around this? Should I go back to traditional form submission. I noticed that google chrome bases autofill values on `names` and `id`s. Check out [this JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ekeyap/4/edit). I don't understand why the code I took from amazon doesn't work (Example 4). Without re-doing my entire form submission, I wonder if there are sufficiently common class names out there in use, so that the user will be filling out a part of an address field `class="addressLine1"` and just is statistically pretty likely to have filled out an email input with the name `email`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea. If you want to have a specific list of pulldown values for each input field on the page. Then with a little javascript, googles closure compiler and knowledge of creating a favourite/bookmark for your browser, you could add yourself something similar on any web page.

Here is my example code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/u2heS/)

HTML

```
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" list="sitelist" />
<datalist id="sitelist">
    <option label="Lorem" value="Lorem">
    <option label="Ipsum" value="Ipsum">
    <option label="Dolor" value="Dolor">
</datalist>
```

Javascript

```
(function () {
    var d = "proin vestibulum ipsum vel tortor sollicitudin luctus".split(" "),
        l = document.createElement("datalist");

    l.id = "myDynamicDatalist";
    d.forEach(function (w) {
        var o = document.createElement("option");
        o.label = w;
        o.value = w;
        l.appendChild(o);
    });

    document.body.appendChild(l);

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("input"), function (e) {
        if (e.list === null || e.list === "") {
            e.setAttribute("list", l.id);
        }
    });
}());
```

Now using [Google's closure compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home), you can get rid of all the whitespace and shorten things to a single line of text just by by setting the option to "simple", and you end up with this.

```
(function(){var b=document.createElement("datalist");b.id="myDynamicDatalist";"proin vestibulum ipsum vel tortor sollicitudin luctus".split(" ").forEach(function(a){var c=document.createElement("option");c.label=a;c.value=a;b.appendChild(c)});document.body.appendChild(b);Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("input"),function(a){(null===a.list||""===a.list)&&a.setAttribute("list",b.id)})})();
```

Now prepend to that line with `javascript:` and save it as a favourite/bookmark and you have created yourself a [javascript bookmarklet](http://dbushell.com/2012/05/22/javascript-bookmarklets/).

Give it a go. click your favourite/bookmark here on SO and then double click the search box, voila!.

You can even create bookmarklet with jquery, and jqueryui meaning that you could use their autocomplete.

Comment: I don't really understand how this is useful. I have to "presupply" a list of to-be-autofilled words?

Comment: This was simple example, think a little outside of that box, a more complex example would be that the code would also monitor inputs on a page, and store information that you type into localStorage, then when you visit that page again, this is not cross domain, it would use the saved data to supply the autocompleter. Yes you would have to write some of this code yourself, I haven't seen anything out there in the wild, but it's not so difficult, and then you could use something like I demonstrated or jquery autocomplete, or YUI autocomplete. This is a plausible solution to your question.

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps I was a little hasty. With a little work, it could be pretty useful. Have an upvote! And my apologies! I'll take a deeper look at it when I have a minutes. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a browser-dependent feature. Browsers presumably look at the ID and/or name of the text input field and save the value you enter.

It may be spotty because of the ID/name of the input fields used on the web sites you visit.

Comment: Check out my JSBIN. Why would it work for the input I took from the amtrak.com website, but not for the input I took from the amazon.com website? http://jsbin.com/ekeyap/4/edit

Answer (score 0):

The browser gives you past filled values based on the input type and name.

So when someone codes a form in examplea.com with an input named "login", when you go on exampleb.com and have an input named "login" as well, the browser will detect that and you already had some info filled for an input named "login" before and show you some options.

That's the browser behavior.

For a jQuery option, you can use jQuery UI's Autocomplete at http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/